# Graphics card drivers no longer working in kali linux

Tags: drivers, kali-linux

I am running Kali Linux, Linux Mint, and Ubuntu.  I was testing out a bootable usb drive that I had tried to make of puppy linux, and it did not work.  So, I restarted my computer and went to boot Kali, which is my main, but I was greeted by a black screen.  I waited for ten or so minutes, just to be sure, and when nothing was happening I rebooted again.  This time, I booted into Mint.  Everything worked fine, so I rebooted again and booted into Kali recovery mode.  This works as well.  Because of this, I think it is a driver issue, but I am not sure.  I even tried to update the video drivers through recovery mode, but I got errors trying to install packages saying that I didn't have enough space.  I am sure that this is not true though, because Kali has used 250 gigs of space on a 500 gig partition.  Is it a viable option to just backup all of by data, remove Kali and start again?  This would not be my first choice if any one here can come up with a better solution, but I am willing to try anything.

Secondary Question (for those familiar with Kali):
If I were to copy all of my Kali data, would I need to copy everything in `/` to maintain all my personalized settings, or can I just copy the contents of `/root, /usr, and /etc`?

Comment: You probably want to make a copy of you data anyway, whether you are to reinstall all or not... at least the important bit. Otherwise, you may want to look at your logs in link with whatever Kali uses to start... X11, NVidia, etc. whatever matches what hardware and software combo you are using there. Logs will often tell you what the real culprit is.

Comment: Besides looking at the logs, the first thing to do is to compare kernel versions (and driver versions). If Kali has an older kernel than Mint, upgrade the Kali kernel and see if it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This actually happened to me. I found out that my partition was full, and it was causing updates nit to be installed. Because if this, my graphics drivers were not starting, and I was just seeing a black screen. It is pretty obvious how to fix it in your case. Just boot into Mint and resize the partition. That should fix it and you should be able to boot normally into Kali.